# Term or identity for sum of the grad of each cartesian component

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

If we have a vector field $\vec{A} = A_x \hat{x} + A_y \hat{y} + A_z \hat{z}$, is there a special term, symbolic representation or identity that can let me represent the vector $\nabla A_x + \nabla A_y + \nabla A_z$ in terms of only $\vec{A}$, **independent of any coordinate system**?

Thanks in advance...

**Updated**

As advised by @joriki, I'll summarize the answer:

$$\nabla \left(\vec{A} \cdot \left(\hat{x} + \hat{y} + \hat{z}\right)\right) = \nabla \left( A_x  + A_y  + A_z  \right) = \nabla A_x  + \nabla A_y + \nabla A_z $$

$\left(\hat{x} + \hat{y} + \hat{z}\right)$ is a constant vector of magnitude $\sqrt{3}$.

However it appears that we can't do this in a manner independent of the coordinate system--the choice of the vector $\left(\hat{x} + \hat{y} + \hat{z}\right)$ depends on the reference directions chosen to decompose $\vec{A}$.

Comment: Is there a particular context in which you came upon this kind of expression?

Comment: I was looking at the 3D wave equation for vector fields, and came across Kirchhoff's formula addressing the solution when the field is a scalar. I was trying to map that to vector fields, and that's where I got this (each cartesian component  of the vector field is a scalar, so...)

Comment: For scalar fields, you get $\partial^2_t \varphi = \nabla^2 \varphi$.  For vector fields, the same equation holds, but $\nabla^2 A = \nabla( \nabla \cdot A) - \nabla \times (\nabla \times A)$ for some vector field $A$. Is that not the wave equation for vector fields?

Comment: How about $\nabla \vec{A}\cdot\vec{k}$ where $\vec{k}$ is a constant vector for the direction you choose?

Comment: @Muphrid -- yes, that is indeed the wave equation for vector fields. I'm trying to see how to express the _solution_ to such an equation. Kirchhoff's formula does that for 3-d scalar fields given the values at t=0 for the field and its time derivative ... is there a way to do the same for vector fields?

Comment: @achille -- thanks, $\nabla (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{k})$ for $\vec{k} = \hat{x} + \hat{y} + \hat{z}$ seems to do the trick.

Comment: One of you should write that as an answer so it can be accepted and the question doesn't remain marked as unanswered.

Comment: The equation $$\vec{A} \cdot \left(\hat{x} + \hat{y} + \hat{z}\right)= A_x \hat{x} + A_y \hat{y} + A_z \hat {z}$$ which appears in your update makes no sense: The LHS is a scalar, the RHS a vector.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter -- Oops, you're right of course. I've corrected that now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We are given a vector field ${\bf x}\mapsto{\bf A}({\bf x})$ in $\Bbb R^3$, i.e., a law that "attaches" to each point ${\bf x}$ of some domain $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^3$ a vector ${\bf A}({\bf x})\in T_{\bf x}$. Here $T_{\bf x}$ denotes the tangent space at ${\bf x}$. If one writes out everything in coordinates one has
$${\bf A}({\bf x})=\bigl[A_1(x_1,x_2,x_3),A_2(x_1,x_2,x_3),A_3(x_1,x_2,x_3)\bigr]^\top\ ,$$
so that formally ${\bf A}$ has the same appearance as a map ${\bf f}:\ \Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$.

Now we want to investigate the "infinitesimal change" of ${\bf A}$ when we move from a given point ${\bf p}\in\Omega$ to a nearby point ${\bf p}+{\bf X}$. When the increment ${\bf A}({\bf p}+{\bf X})-{\bf A}({\bf p})$ satisfies a relation of the form
$${\bf A}({\bf p}+{\bf X})-{\bf A}({\bf p})=L.{\bf X} + o\bigl(|{\bf X}|\bigr)\qquad ({\bf X}\to{\bf 0})$$
for some linear map $L:\ \Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ then ${\bf A}$ is called *differentiable* at ${\bf p}$, and $L=:d{\bf A}({\bf p})$ is the *differential* or *derivative* of ${\bf A}$ at ${\bf p}$.

Since $d{\bf A}({\bf p})$ is, similarly to the Jacobian of an ${\bf f}:\ \Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$, a linear map $\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$ **it is not possible to represent it by a vector**. This contrasts the differential $df$ of a scalar function, where $df({\bf p})$ can be represented by the gradient vector $\nabla f({\bf p})$.

In terms of coordinates and matrices $d{\bf A}({\bf p})$ is described by
$$d{\bf A}({\bf p}).{\bf X}=\left[\matrix{A_{1.1}& A_{1.2}& A_{1.3} \cr
A_{2.1}& A_{2.2}& A_{2.3}\cr
A_{3.1}& A_{3.2}& A_{3.3}\cr}\right]_{\bf p}\ \left[\matrix{X_1\cr X_2\cr X_3\cr}\right]\ .$$
In the rows of the matrix $\bigl[d{\bf A}({\bf p})\bigr]$ we see the gradients $\nabla A_i$ $\ (1\leq i\leq 3)$, evaluated at ${\bf p}$, of the coordinate functions describing ${\bf A}$.

A final remark: Your vector $\hat x+\hat y+\hat z$, in my notation: ${\bf e}_1+{\bf e}_2+{\bf e}_3$, does not play any rôle here.